# Is this the best way to get the MAX - 1 of a column?

Tags: sql-server

We have a table with a column called `JOBNUM`, which is an alphanumeric column that has values like `ABC-101A, ABC-102F, XYZ-254D, etc.` The values are assigned sequentially. This gets the latest one:

```
SELECT MAX(JOBNUM) FROM WEEKLY.dbo.Jobs_all
```

I needed a way to get the previous JOBNUM, not the latest one. This seems to work...unless someone has a better idea...?

```
SELECT MAX(JOBNUM) FROM WEEKLY.dbo.Jobs_All 
WHERE JOBNUM NOT IN (SELECT MAX(JOBNUM) FROM WEEKLY.dbo.Jobs_all)
```

Comment: Does `SELECT JOBNUM FROM WEEKLY.dbo.Jobs_all ORDER BY JOBNUM DESC OFFSET 1 ROW FETCH NEXT 1 ROW` work? I don’t really know SQL Server, but found [some docs](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg699618(v=sql.110).aspx) that suggested it might….

Comment: @ryan that works provided they are in Azure or 2016 I versions I think.

Comment: offset fetch is available from  versions greater than>= 2012 and this works better as well

Comment: Too much time in ORACLE/HANA since 2008 :P

Comment: @Ryan I need a moderator! I Just hit a reputation of `7777` - can you block people from upvoting my posts ;-)

Comment: @KobyDouek: That’s about two thousand clicks’ worth of locking – I’m afraid you’ll probably get another vote before I finish =(

Comment: The line 

SELECT JOBNUM FROM WEEKLY.dbo.Jobs_all ORDER BY JOBNUM DESC OFFSET 1 ROW FETCH NEXT 1 ROW

gives me an error INCORRECT SYNTAX NEAR 'ROW'

Comment: @KobyDouek I think you're late.  I thought 7337 was more desired.

Comment: @BrianBattles odd... https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg699618(v=sql.110).aspx shows `rows` and `row` are interchangeable.

Answer (score 4):

That's a pretty good direction.

2 more efficient ways:

```
SELECT (JOBNUM) FROM WEEKLY.dbo.Jobs_All ORDER BY JOBNUM DESC LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1
```

Or:

```
SELECT MAX(JOBNUM) FROM WEEKLY.dbo.Jobs_All 
WHERE JOBNUM < (SELECT MAX(JOBNUM) FROM WEEKLY.dbo.Jobs_all)
```

Using `<` is more efficient (faster) than using `NOT IN`.

Comment: More efficient as in better (faster) performance or accuracy?

Comment: @Simon Faster. But since the `MAX` selection returns 1 result, a very very little bit faster.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on < instead of NOT IN.

I don't believe LIMIT can be used in SQL Server

Comment: @BrianBattles Yeah it's available

Comment: @BrianBattles which version though?

Comment: SQL Server 2014

Comment: Koby, Microsoft's documentation on SQL Server don't seem to show LIMIT

Comment: @BrianBattles could you  try: `SELECT top 1 JOBNUM FROM WEEKLY.dbo.Jobs_All ORDER BY JOBNUM DESC OFFSET 1`

Answer (score 1):

Using a CTE and a row_number() window function gives you greater flexablity.

```
WITH CTE AS (
SELECT row_number() over (order by jobNum desc) , jobNum
FROM WEEKLY.dbo.Jobs_All)
SELECT * 
FROM CTE 
WHERE RN = 2
```

Comment: Was just about to post the same. :)

Comment: I was trying to figure out how to do it in a cross apply and gave up  though Limit and offset seem like a good/best approach

Answer (score 0):

here's how

```
SELECT MAX(JOBNUM) FROM WEEKLY.dbo.Jobs_All WHERE JOBNUM < (SELECT MAX(JOBNUM) FROM WEEKLY.dbo.Jobs_all)
```

hope this helps!